# i want to change online to offline in facebook through php sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to convert my online presence from online to offline and viceversa in facebook....
Is there any api to do this..

Can i update the fb database...like using fql

```
$fql="update from user set online_presence = 'offline' where uid =$uid";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that! Most of the tables, if not all, are read-only.